# ASP.NET Gridview won't change backcolor for some rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the colour of the row of a gridview depending on a value in one of the cells. However it only partially works. Here is the code:

```
protected void attn_list_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "P") //change the colour of rows
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#CCDDCC");
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "L")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#C5DAFC");
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "E")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FFCC66");
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "U")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("FFCECE");
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "N")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("EDC9FF");
        }
        if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text == "Yes")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[5].ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red); //if EL, set colour of font as red
        }
    }
```

And the outcome:
[image: outcome]

I tried to test the conditions by putting in `System.Diagnostic.Debug.Writeline("A")` into the `else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text=="N")` statement, and turns out it printed "A", meaning it actually met the conditions. Just that I don't know why the colour won't get changed...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the more code, the more we glance over it!

so, converting above to this:

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string sColor = "";
            switch(e.Row.Cells[4].Text)
            {
              case "P": sColor = "#CCDDCC"; break;
              case "L": sColor = "#C5DAFC"; break;
              case "E": sColor = "#FFCC66"; break;
              case "U": sColor = "FFCC66"; break;
              case "N": sColor = "EDC9FF"; break;
            }
            if (sColor != "")
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName(sColor);

            if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text == "Yes")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[5].ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Red); //if EL, set colour of font as red
            }
        }
```

Hum, sure looks like you missing the "#" for some of your colors.

Also, note how we check if data bound is actually procssing a data row, the header and other types of "rows" are tossed to that routine, so we should (need) a check for the row type also.

but, so far, it looks like the "# is missing.